# Converting to double is giving not accurate number

Tags: c#

Convert.ToDouble is adding zeros and 1 like in this picture:

[image]

Why it is turning from 21.62 to 21.620000000000001 ?
Is this about floating point issue?

Comment: Yes, it is a floating point issue.

Comment: @uzay95 Is this about floating point issue? Yes it is.

Comment: Pictures are definitely helpful but it would be nice if you accompanied them with a textual representation of the offending code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double (and Float) are [floating-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) types, and in a binary system will have some imprecision.

If you need more precise comparisons use `decimal` instead.  If you're just doing calculations `double` should be fine.  If you need to compare doubles for absolute equiality then compare the absolute value of the difference to some small constant:

```
if (a == b)  // not reliable for floating point
{ 
    ....
}

double EPSILON = 0.0000001;
if (Math.Abs(a-b) < EPSILON)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: If you're suggesting using `System.Double.Epsilon` then be aware that the difference between two doubles will likely be greater than that value : (from MSDN) If you create a custom algorithm that determines whether two floating-point numbers can be considered equal, you must use a value that is greater than the Epsilon constant to establish the acceptable absolute margin of difference for the two values to be considered equal. (Typically, that margin of difference is many times greater than Epsilon.)

Answer (score 3):

The floating point numbers have some problems of approximation.
This is because decimal fraction like 0,00001 can't be represented exactly on a binary system (where fractional numbers are represented in module q/p).
The problem is intrinsic.

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes; between any two bases (in this case, 2 and 10), there are always values that can expressed w/ a finite number of "decimal" (binimal?) places in one that cannot in the other.

Comment: Actually, the bases must be coprime for that to be true.  Any fraction with a finite number of places in base 2 will have a finite number of places in base 4, 8, 16, etc., and vice versa.

Comment: Nice call; that's what happens why I pretend to be a mathematician!

Answer (score 0):

Rounding errors like this are common in almost every high level programming language. In Java, to get around this you use a class called BigDecimal if you need guaranteed accuracy. Otherwise, you can just write a method that rounds a decimal to the nearest place you need.

Comment: Downvoters should comment. This doesn't seem like such a bad answer.

Comment: Well, I did not give a C# specific answer and just kind of said "Go look for a library class", which is not the greatest I guess :/

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would add that the behavior is not really determined by the language; the language just says "IEEE double is one of the data types you can use."  The behavior is actually specified by the IEEE.